# How to specify execution on a specific port in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, port

I have a script to run a service:

```
#!/bin/bash
export HOME=/home/recusr

cd /home/recusr/pasayobloques/blokes/
su myUser -c meteor -- port 9999   
exit
```

But I get the following error message when running it:

```
su unrecognized option '--port'
```

Comment: Did you type `-- port` or `--port`? The script shows `-- port` with a space but the error says `--port` with no space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entire command argument to `su` must be a single argument.

```
su myUser -c 'meteor --port 9999'
```

In your script, `--port` is being interpreted as the next argument to `su`, not part of the command after `-c`.